# array of char from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toast

I have trouble with displaying Toasts
I want show every char item from the EditText field.
But when I debug it on my phone it just freezes and dont want do the task.
How can I correct it?

```
package com.example.translit;
import android.R.string;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private OnClickListener mclick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bla-bla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            EditText txtEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnter);
            //EditText txtOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOut);

            for(int i=1;i<txtEnter.length()+1;i++){
                String str = txtEnter.getText().toString();
                char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), charArray[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }

    };  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        Button mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTr);
        mbutton.setOnClickListener(mclick);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
 for(int i=1;i<txtEnter.length()+1;i++){
                String str = txtEnter.getText().toString();
                char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), charArray[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

to this:

```
 String str = txtEnter.getText().toString();
 char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
 for(int i=1;i<txtEnter.length();i++){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), charArray[i] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

you want to go over with the for loop only on displaying the text, not retrieving it out of the edit text

make note that possibly because the operating is too fast, you will only see the last 2 or 3 letters

Comment: same thing. It freezes after button click.

Comment: Then "Sorry! The... has stoped unexpectedly..."

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str = txtEnter.getText().toString();    
    for(int i=1;i<txtEnter.length()+1;i++){

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str.charAt(i) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not correct. You should go from `i=0` to `i<txtEnter.length()`.